My Pull Refresh not functioning in WebView Compose
I have a simple WebPageView.kt that I can call on in other pages that embed webviews in my app. It was working fine with the LinearProgressIndicatorProgress to display a progress bar for each webpage.
But, as I am trying to also add a PullRefreshIndicator, the Pull Refresh does not seem to work.
I wonder what is wrong in my code, please.
WebPageView.kt

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun WebViewPage(url: String) {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    var isRefreshing by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }


    //WEB-VIEW


    val webView = remember(context) {
        WebView(context).apply {
            webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            loadUrl(url)
            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            settings.useWideViewPort = true
            setBackgroundColor(0x000000)
            webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
                override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView?, newProgress: Int) {
                    LinearProgressIndicatorProgress = newProgress / 100f
                }
            }
        }
    }

    val pullRefreshState = rememberPullRefreshState(
        refreshing = isRefreshing,
        onRefresh = {
            isRefreshing = true
            webView.reload()
        }
    )

    //PROGRESS INDICATOR FOR WEB-VIEW

    Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContext provides context) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .pullRefresh(pullRefreshState)
            ) {
                Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    if (LinearProgressIndicatorProgress < 1f) {
                        LinearProgressIndicator(
                            progress = LinearProgressIndicatorProgress,
                            color = Color(0xffae52de),
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                        )
                    }
                    AndroidView(
                        factory = { webView },
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                    )
                }


                //PULL-TO-REFRESH

                PullRefreshIndicator(
                    refreshing = isRefreshing,
                    state = pullRefreshState,
                    contentColor = Color(0xffae52de),
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter)
                )

                if (isRefreshing) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Pull to refresh",
                        color = Color(0xffae52de),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
                            .padding(top = 60.dp) // Adjust the padding as needed
                    )
                }
            }
        }


        LaunchedEffect(webView) {
            webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                    isRefreshing = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
private var LinearProgressIndicatorProgress by mutableStateOf(0f)


Any thoughts on this, please?

As per documentation:

Note that this modifier must be added above a scrolling container, such as a lazy column, in order to receive scroll events.

Column isn't scrollable by default, you have to apply a modifier to it:
.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())


Wow, I did not notice that. I am really grateful. Please pardon my ignorance, but where in particular should I use the modifier? As the only column I see is the one for the LinearProgressIndicator?

Oh, just a minute… am I to wrap if (isRefreshing) {..} in a lazy column and apply the modifier, please?

Just add this modifier to the only Column you have. @MaryKay

Alright, will give it a try.

It worked! How wonderful! How do I let the WebView go down when the PullRefresh is triggered?
The PullRefresh with its text Pull to Refresh display over the webpage view. I wish the webpage view could drop down a little to reveal a little white space with the PullRefreshIndicator and  Pull to Refresh text showing, and bounce back up upon completion, please.

Just move the if with that text between the LinearProgressIndicator and AndroidView? @MaryKay
